# is service book entry for IPPP a prerequisite for Blackberry push service work?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to test sample application for Push API,that comes with Push SDK. Though was able configure server side application and was able to hit test URLs given in [PDF](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/14465/BlackBerry_Push_Service_SDK-Getting_Started_Guide--1015058-0316055614-001-1.0.0.5-US.pdf) and was able to get expected results.
But am not able to run Client side sample application.Its LOG was showing following error when I was trying to register for the service after prerequisite setting.

```
Content Provider network command[Subscribe] failed, caused by could not find a service book
entry for IPPP command register failed with error:java.io.IOException: Network Opertation[Subscribe] failed. Make sure that Content Provider  URL is accessible
```

Can we test Push enabled application on simulator,If yes, is there any specific setting required for the same?

Comment: Are you doing this on a simulator or real device?  Are you using the MDS simulator or a real BES?

Comment: Am using simulator.And using BIS for push service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testing of BIS is not allowed on simulator,for testing Push services through BIS one need real device only.
Since the Push server needs a PIN number, and that all simulator got the same PIN , so I needed a real device and an Dataplan to test it.

The reason behind is,they can't reach a Simulator because simulators are not on any known Carrier.

Comment: I test the example in a real device but I obtain the same exception. How you can run it?

Answer (score 1):

not all devices have the same pin. the pin can be changed from jde->edit->preferences->simulator. check out this link:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6338/Testing_push_applications_607571_11.jsp